# Spring Integration: how to read selected messages from a queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

If I have one queue and multiple subscribers, how do I code the subscribers to only remove the messages they are interested in? I can use a [PublishSubscribeChannel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel) to send the message to all subscribers, but it has no filtering feature, and I'm not clear if the messages are ever removed after delivery. Another option is to read all messages, and filter in the subscriber, but then I need to invent a Kafka-ish behavior for message indexing to prevent messages already seen being processed again.

Comment: Why not use Apache kafka with topic, subscribers don't have to read all messages, but instead the messages from the topic.

Comment: @triffic Kafka is somewhat overkill for me. I'm looking for something in-memory.

Comment: ok, how about taking a try [Redis Pub/Sub] https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Answer (score 1):

Well, indeed there is no such a `persistent topic` abstraction in Spring Integration out-of-the-box. However, since you say you need an in-memory solution, how about to consider to start embedded ActiveMQ and use `Jms.publishSubscribeChannel()` based on the `Topic` destination? Right, there is still no `selector` from the Spring Integration subscribers even for this type of the `MessageChannel`, but you still can use `.filter()` to discard messages you are not interested in.

The same you can reach with the Hazelcast `ITopic`:

```
    @Bean
    public ITopic<Message<?>> siTopic() {
        return hazelcastInstance().getTopic("siTopic");
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subscriber1() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Flux.create(messageFluxSink ->
                        siTopic()
                                .addMessageListener(message ->
                                        messageFluxSink.next(message.getMessageObject()))))
                .filter("headers.myHeader == foo")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subscriber2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Flux.create(messageFluxSink ->
                        siTopic()
                                .addMessageListener(message ->
                                        messageFluxSink.next(message.getMessageObject()))))
                .filter("headers.myHeader == bar")
                .get();
    }
```

Well, actually looking to your plain in-memory model, I even would say that simple `QueueChannel` and `bridge` to the `PublishSubscribeChannel` with the mentioned filter in each subscriber should be fully enough for you:

```
    @Bean
    public PollableChannel queueChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @BridgeFrom("queueChannel")
    public MessageChannel publishSubscribeChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subscriber1() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(publishSubscribeChannel())
                .filter("headers.myHeader == foo")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subscriber2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(publishSubscribeChannel())
                .filter("headers.myHeader == bar")
                .get();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

And one more option to use instead of `PublishSubscribeChannel` and `filter` combination is like `RecipientListRouter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter

Comment: I’ve taken a different approach using Spring Batch. One of the questions I ask myself is “has someone else already solved this problem? If not, can I use a different approach?” Thus, I cant accept tor answer as of yet, since I didn’t implement the suggestions. I’ve done the next best thing, upvote :)

Comment: How do you use Spring Batch though? Would you mind to share your experience? Maybe even as an independent answer to your own question? Thanks. Feel free to raise a JIRA for Spring Integration with your request, if you see some general solution with a pure Spring Integration though...

Comment: I'll email you more details, to the email address available on GitHub. I'm considering creating a ticket or PR for SI; if I do, you'll of course see it.

Comment: I've sent you an email with details.